# python - lambda filters

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to understand lambda filters in Python. What i am struggling to understand is the the usage of the "in x, people" clause in the lambda filter. I read the purpose of the filter as: return those values for which the condition "height" is TRUE in the sequence (people). i would thus initially have thought it would be "lambda x: "height" in people). Why is it x, people? What is my thinking error? Many thanks in advance!

```
people = [{'name': 'Mary', 'height': 160},
          {'name': 'Isla', 'height': 80},
          {'name': 'Sam'}]

heights = map(lambda x: x['height'],
              filter(lambda x: 'height' in x, people))

print(heights) #(160,80)
```

Comment: There is no `in x, people` but `(lambda x: 'height' in x), people` - `filter(first_argument_lambda, second_argument_list)`

Answer (score 1):

I think one variable name change should be sufficient to explain it:

```
filter(lambda person: 'height' in person, people)
```

You're check for every **person** whether that person has a height. You're not checking if "people has a height", because that doesn't make sense. `people` is a collection, and only **elements of that collection** can have a height, not the collection itself.

Here's an equivalent line:

```
(person for person in people if 'height' in person)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline lambdas can be a bit confusing. To understand them better, you first need to understand what lambdas are: They are just functions.

You could write your code like this too:

```
def getHeightValue (x):
    return x['height']

def containsHeight (x):
    return 'height' in x

heights = map(getHeightValue, filter(containsHeight, people))
```

So as you can see, the `, people` part is not part of the lambda, but part of the `filter` call. `filter(function, iterable)` just filters the `iterable` for those elements `x` for which `function(x)` returns true.

From above code, you can then convert those short functions to lambdas:

```
getHeightValue = lambda x: x['height']
containsHeight = lambda x: 'height' in x

heights = map(getHeightValue, filter(containsHeight, people))
```

That is literally the same thing.

And since you don’t need to store those functions in a variable, you can just inline them into the `map` and `filter` call, which is then your original code.

Note that you could use list comprehensions here to make the logic maybe a bit more visible. List comprehensions allow you to combine `map` and `filter` into a single syntax. It would be basically look like this:

```
[getHeightValue(x) for x in people if containsHeight(x)]
```

And when you inline those functions again, you get this which is still pretty readable:

```
[x['height'] for x in people if 'height' in x]
```

… or with a better variable name:

```
[person['height'] for person in people if 'height' in person]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `in x, people` but `(lambda x: 'height' in x), people` - `filter(first_argument_lambda_function, second_argument_people_list)`